# Pandas frame complex self join

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

if I have the following frame

```
id    | value
A     | 50
B     | 20
C     | 10
A;B   |
C;B   |
A;B;C |
```

What is the smartest way to fill the missing with 70, 30, 80?

I tried to slip the dataframe into two dict and loop but I felt there are much easier way.

My Python is 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get_dummies` with `dot`

```
df.id.str.get_dummies(sep=';').dot([50,20,10])
Out[213]: 
0    50
1    20
2    10
3    70
4    30
5    80
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Neat -- `df.id.str.get_dummies(';').dot(df.dropna().set_index('id'))`

Answer (score 2):

A crude way using `apply`

```
In [15]: mapper = df.dropna().set_index('id')['value'].to_dict()

In [16]:  df.id.apply(lambda x: sum(map(mapper.get, x.split(';'))))
Out[16]:
0    50.0
1    20.0
2    10.0
3    70.0
4    30.0
5    80.0
Name: id, dtype: float64
```